# Programmatically find the IP address of the desktop over USB tethering

Tags: android, usb

Is there a way to find the IP address of the desktop machine connected the android phone after USB tethering is turned on?

Does android assign a fixed IP address to the desktop? Or does it assign a dynamic address (dhcp)? Is there a PPP connection created between the phone and machine?

Answer (score 0):

With USB tethering it seems that all android devices use the same static addresses, the android device using tcpdump is 192.168.42.129

The attached device will get a DHCP provided address in the same address range.

I listen to a port on my android app and have a udev rule to push the dhclient address back to that port on my app.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, in usb tethering mode the phone is acting as the computer's modem, so the PC's IP would be the phone's IP.

Comment: Two computers on the same network will never have the exact same IP.